# HashMap Values Erased In Multiple Function Calls

Tags: java, parsing, hashmap

I am using the Java HashMap class as a "cache" for a language parser. I'll first give a brief background into the parser, and then explain the issue.

Each time the parsing function is called, the input is turned into an array of custom objects, which are represented in the language's grammar. For simplicity's sake, we'll call them Words. For example:

"the red house"
[THE, RED, HOUSE] (ArrayList of Words)

A parsing algorithm is then run on this ArrayList. To make our parser more efficient, we thought of storing this ArrayList object in a HashMap, mapped onto the output parse. Whenever we encounter an identical ArrayList, we can just return the stored parse.

The stored procedure goes fine. After inserting the object into the HashMap, the printed value of the HashMap contains the key (ArrayList) and the value (Parse). Code below:

```
this.typeCache.put(WordList, Parse);
```

In which WordList is the ArrayList, and Parse is the parse (obviously). Later, when I try to retrieve from the cache, the system recognizes that the WordList is a key, but the value it retrieves is null.

```
if (this.typeCache.keySet().contains(WordList)) { 
    System.out.println("Retrieving from type Cache.");
    return this.typeCache.get(WordList);
}
```

I ensured that the stored value Parse is a clone of the field parse object (which changes each iteration), so that the object isn't changing. It's also not that the HashMap gets wiped each iteration, because I print it out on each function call, and the keys stay there. It seems to be just the values that are changing.

Is there a reason why this would happen? Let me know if you need more information.

EDIT: The "Parse" value is technically just a PriorityQueue of different possible parses. I believe the class was customized to contain a "clone" method, which is pasted below :

```
public PriorityQueue<E> clone() {
    PriorityQueue<E> clonePQ = new PriorityQueue<E>();
    clonePQ.size = size;
    clonePQ.capacity = capacity;
    clonePQ.elements = new ArrayList<E>(capacity);
    clonePQ.priorities = new double[capacity];
    if (size() > 0) {
        clonePQ.elements.addAll(elements);
        System.arraycopy(priorities, 0, clonePQ.priorities, 0, size());
    }
    return clonePQ;
}
```

Comment: Does this actually print `null` directly, or is it just the contents of `Parse`?  Can we see the logic used to clone it?

Comment: Are you sure the `Parse` you put in is actually not `null`?

Comment: Although it might not be causing this specific issue, you probably want to use something that is immutable for your key. It's hard to tell from such a small snipit what the problem is. You might see if typeCache.containsKey(WordList) gives you the same result.

Comment: I changed to "containsKey(WordList)" but it's the same result. I can add the cloning logic to the question. I'm sure the Parse I put in isn't null because the first time I print the HashMap, the value shows up. But when the method gets called again, the key remains the same, but the value disappears.

Comment: From so little code it is impossible for us to find out where the problem is. But just a long shot: you might want to try to clone the WordList as well as the Parse, because especially for the key it is very important that it is not modified as long as it's a key in an ArrayList.

Comment: That's a good suggestion - I changed the key (WordList) to a clone / copy but it was the same result, unfortunately. If I figure out what's causing it I can post the solution here, in case anyone else runs into the same issue. Thanks for your help.